# Will Google Map JS API 3 require an API key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I did not find any indication that I would need an API key, and in fact I am using it without one. Did they announce that they were doing away with API keys or that the key would be implemented later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [says](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html), "This version of the Google Maps JavaScript API no longer needs API keys!"  However, I don't see (or expect) a commitment that they won't require one again later.